# Implicit cast from int to byte in C#

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

So I was writing some C# code today and I was rather surprised when I got the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I read around a bit and apparently, this is not possible without an explicit conversion.

I have been working for weeks with a C# project where this conversion is happening all over the place without any errors. So, my question is, where do you change this behavior? It's obviously possible.

Comment: You sure you're not thinking of implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`?

Comment: Care to show some code that's working?

Comment: Well, damn. I must have missed something. I thought it was working. Way to come off as a complete moron. :/

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. You can implicitly cast a `byte` to an `int` without any written cast, but not the other way since an `int` can be a number that overflows a `byte`.

Comment: This actually works with `const int` variables with values smaller than a byte.